# How can I clean up my MacPorts installation?

Tags: macos, macports

Which command should I run to

- delete all old port versions
- delete downloaded files
- temp files created during build
- all other stuff which I don't need when I am sure that updated version works fine

I got a suggestion to use

```
port clean --all all
```

but it tries to clean ports I don't have, though I tried

```
port clean --all installed
```

but it did not delete old inactive versions, then

```
port -u uninstall
```

but it got stuck saying that `py25-nose` (which is active) depends on `py25-setuptools` (which is inactive).

Answer (score 115, accepted):

The suggestions you received cover what you're after:

```
sudo port -f clean --all all
sudo port -f uninstall inactive
```

If you can't wait for the clean one to run in the background, there are a few commands you can run manually and faster.

Remove leftover build files (this is done automatically by default):

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/var/macports/build/*
```

Remove download files:

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/*
```

Remove archives (these aren't created by default):

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/local/var/macports/packages/*
```

Comment: What about deleting inactive ports taking into account problem with py25-nose which I described?

Comment: port -f uninstall inactive

Comment: Updated to add it since you're after two separate things.

Comment: Thanks! When I did a macports upgrade it started downloading about 15 GiB of tex stuff I didn't want. I was panicking about how to remove the crap. Thank you!

Comment: I have 1.8 GiB of .tbz2 archives in /opt/local/var/macports/software surely they can go... according to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64074/macports-software-clean-up-opt-local-var-macports-software they can be deleted

Comment: // , I get the following problem when I attempt this:  `$ sudo port -f uninstall inactive
sudo: cannot get working directory
error getting working directory name: no such file or directory
    while executing
"pwd"
    invoked from within
"set current_portdir [pwd]"
    (file "/opt/local/bin/port" line 5260)`

Comment: // , Hold on, problem solved. I just had to close the terminal that gave me that error. Apparently these commands mess with the environment variables, or something.

Answer (score 9):

```
port uninstall inactive
```

is the way to go.

Comment: Still complains about py25-nose depending on py25-setuptools

Comment: "port -f uninstall inactive" will force this behavior to be overridden.

Comment: @tig This is a bug with the old registry format and is fixed when using the sqlite registry introduced with 1.9. The announce for 1.9.0 has instructions how to switch: http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-announce/2010-June/000008.html

Comment: @Raim: Thank you very much! `leaves` pseudo name will be of a great help for me!

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add my experiences with the above in case it helps anyone else: When I ran

`port clean --all all`

it ran for several minutes, and this made me concerned, so I interrupted the process.

I too, wanted to "clean up" after multiple installs of Macports on Yosemite. I had installed first via Terminal, and then did

`rm -rf MacPorts-2.3.3` which I realized does not clean up, because I saw the command `port` stopped working.

**My solution:**  I installed again with the pkg installer, which doesn't leave any directories behind.

Comment: // , Thanks for the answer! Does the `pkg` installer work with macports, or should I uninstall macports before using `pkg`?

Comment: I followed Macports' recommendation: the pkg or dmg [installer][1] depending on your Mac OS version. I did not have to manually remove, or uninstall any old versions, directories, etc. when using the installer. For example, I recently updated from Yosemite to El Capitan, and Macports had to be re-installed. 

You could later perform maintanance with some [common tasks][2] and commands like `sudo port selfupdate` and `sudo port upgrade outdated`

Hth!

  [1]: https://www.macports.org/install.php
  [2]: https://guide.macports.org/chunked/using.common-tasks.html