# Is it safe to rm -rf /var/macports?

Tags: macports

So its all in the title,

I've installed a `cpuminer` from *Sourceforge* and the file was corrupted. Now when I look for the name of the file I found something in `/var/macpports`.

Since I'm not using any *macports* installation, can I run `rm -rf /var/macports` or is there something I should know about this folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you are not using *macports* anymore, it is safe for you to delete the
>   `/var/macports`

It was supposed to contain installer packages that you install from *macports*

Refer to [uninstalling macports](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html) & [Cleanup my macports installation](https://superuser.com/a/165670/270195)

Answer (score 4):

Read the full article [here](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#uninstall).

These are for **MacPorts runtime data**. The sub folders are:

**build**

It used during the building of ports. It normally contains empty folders.

**distfiles**

The downloaded sources of each build port.

**packages**

Contains the binary archives of each installed port.

**registry**

Contains detailed information about each installed ports.

**software**

Contains the archive of installed software in compressed format.

**sources**

Contains the Macport sources in different subfolders in different format.

Now removing/uninstalling MacPorts can be a drastic step, and depending on the issue you are experiencing, you may not need to do so. Please ask on the [macports-users](https://lists.macosforge.org/mailman/listinfo/macports-users) mailing list first, if you're unsure.

Comment: Asking for answers to be accepted are frowned upon.  They add unnecessary noise to the comment section.  You should consider improving this answer, you mention a link, answers which contain a link should reference the material from the link and quote all relevant information.  If there is no relevant information to quote (i.e. its a download link) then specify the fact, links which are not quoted really shouldn't be provided though.